# Android Share multiple data between two fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, mvvm

I want to pass two variables between two Fragment after clicking a button. I've read that I can use the ViewModel class but I can't really understand how it works. I also tried with Bundle but it doesn't work. When I click the Button the second Fragment show null on both variables.

First Fragment file:

```
    private FragmentWeightBinding binding;
    private EditText edtNumber;
    private Button addBtn;
    private TextView txtDate;
    String sWeight, currentDateAndTime;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        WeightViewModel weightViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WeightViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentWeightBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();
        addBtn = binding.addBtn;
        edtNumber = binding.edtNumber;
        final String[] weight = {""};
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
        currentDateAndTime = sdf.format(new Date());

        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                weight[0] = edtNumber.getText().toString();
                sWeight = weight[0];
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("Weight", sWeight);
                bundle.putString("Date", currentDateAndTime);

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                WeightTableFragment weightTableFragment = new WeightTableFragment();
                weightTableFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),weight[0] + currentDateAndTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        txtDate= binding.txtDate;
        txtDate.setText(currentDateAndTime);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

}
```

Second Fragment:

```
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "Weight";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "Date";

    private String weight;
    private String date;

    public WeightTableFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static WeightTableFragment newInstance(String sWeight, String currentDateAndTime) {
        WeightTableFragment fragment = new WeightTableFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, sWeight);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, currentDateAndTime);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            weight = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            date = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_weight_table, container, false);

        TextView text = rootView.findViewById(R.id.weightDate);
        text.setText(String.format(date + ": " + weight));

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: You do not have any code here related to either of your proposed approaches. To share a viewmodel between two fragments hosted by the same activity in Java, IIRC, use `new ViewModelProvider(getActivity())` instead of `new ViewModelProvider(this)`, in both fragments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass using bundle (when you create the Empty Fragment the Android Studio provides you basic code) i.e;

```
 private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"; 
 String dataYouWantToSendInFragmentFromActvity;

 public static YourFragmentClassName newInstance(String dataYouWantToSendInFragmentFromActvity) {
        YourFragmentClassName fragment = new YourFragmentClassName ();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, dataYouWantToSendInFragmentFromActvity);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            dataYouWantToSendInFragmentFromActvity = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
    }
```

Now to openFragment from Activity instead of creating the object of Fragment use the getInstance(Object obj) method which will put the data you want to send in a bundle and return you the fragment object

The following code shows how to use it (Point A)

```
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.container, YourFragmentClassName .newInstance("YourStringData"));
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

I have used the String parameter in getInstance() method just for example you can use any primitive data type or Parcelable Object and you can also add more than one object and add in a bundle and assign in onCreate

Now if you want to send data from one Fragment to another make a callback from FragmentA to Activity which will receive the data and send the data to another fragment FragmentB (in its implementation)  in the same manner described above. To get the callback object in FragmentA you can use the override method onAttach() of the fragment as,

```
  Callback callback;
      @Override
        public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            if(context instanceOf CallBack)
              this.callback=context;
        }
```

Now in your case instead of toast call the method of callback maybe callback.openOtherFrag(YOUR_DATA);
this will call the implementation of your openOtherFrag method from Activity and send the data i.e. YOUR_DATA as done in (Point A) above

Happy Coding

Comment: I implemented my code with your answer. I didn't understand the "callback" part but now when i click the button to add the data, in the second fragment i have null on both the data that i have send.

Comment: First read about callbacks